# Automated Tests Hanging TeamCity Build

Tags: automated-testing, specflow, team-city

I am using TeamCity to build a .dll containing a test suite for an api.  The api is composed of asynchronous calls to create/read/update/delete values in a database.  The tests in the .dll were created using specflow, xUnit and c#.  Some of my step definitions call the api methods with non-asynchronous code, like so:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    Task.Run(() => client.ApiCall()).Result;
}
```

The tests that call the api in this fashion are executed successfully by TeamCity.
If however I change the code for that same api call, so that the calling code is asynchronous,

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
 await client.ApiCall();
}
```

the build will hang on that test.

Additionally, I have created a separate project, using XUnit but not SpecFlow, and made the same api call with async and await.  This version of the test does not hang the TeamCity build.